# How can I invoke #new on a Ruby module to instantiate one of its classes?

Tags: ruby, class, constructor, module, adapter

I have the following code:

```
module A

  class B
    def initialize(c, d)
      # do stuff
    end
  end


  class E
    def initialize(f, g)
      # do more stuff
    end
  end

end
```

In other to create an instance of either `B` or `E`, I have to do `A::B.new(c, d)` or `A::E.new(f, g)`.  What I'd like to do is set an adapter for the module and then call `new` directly on the module, i.e.,

```
A.adapter= :b
A.new(c, d) # creates an instance of B
A.adapter= :e
A.new(f, g) # creates an instance of E
```

How can I do this? Do I have to define class getter/setter methods?

Comment: Everything is possible.  But in doing so, you will have created code that is more than a little surprising, because canonically you call `new` only on a class.  If you care about the readability of your code, you might want to rethink.

Answer (score 2):

### Modules Don't Have a Constructor Method

You can't do what you want natively, because one of the differences between Ruby classes and modules is that modules can't be instantiated. If you try, an exception is raised. Consider:

```
module A; end
A.new
```

This will correctly raise `NoMethodError`:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for A:Module

### Create a Factory Method on the Class

You can hack around this by defining `A::new` as a class method, like so:

```
module A
  # Factory to instantiate and return B or C.
  def self.new klass
    const_get(klass).new
  end

  class B; end
  class C; end
end

b = A.new :B
c = A.new 'C'

A.class
#=> Module

[b.class, c.class]
#=> [A::B, A::C]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def A.adapter= klass; @klass = klass end
def A.new *args; const_get(@klass.upcase).new(*args) end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module A
  def self.adapter= klass
    @klass = klass.capitalize
  end

  def self.new x,y
    const_get( @klass ).new x,y
  end

  class B
    def initialize(c, d)
      # do stuff
    end
  end


  class E
    def initialize(f, g)
      # do more stuff
    end
  end
end

A.adapter = :b
puts A.new(:c, :d)
=> #<A::B:0x007fd6320865f0>
```